# AngularJS checkbox not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am creating a simple `angularJs` application for my own learning purpose. I have attached the code snippets below. I have two `JSON` data.

One represents the collection of grocery items and other the items that user selected. If the selected data matches to that of collection data, I am marking the checkbox as checked. I can insert the data on click of the checkbox, but if I randomly start to uncheck, it is not functioning properly. I would appreciate your help for correcting me where I am making mistake. Also, I would appreciate if there is any easy way of comparing `JSON` data. Here I am using `name` to compare. Is there any other simple way of comparing the individual object inside `JSON`, without mentioning `name` or `type` as I did in my example, in `angularJs` or `Javascript`?

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("groceryApp", []).controller("groceryController", groceryControllerFunction);
  groceryControllerFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$filter"];

  function groceryControllerFunction($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.groceryCollection = groceryCollection_JSON;
    $scope.selectedItems = selectedItems_JSON;
    $scope.toggleSelection = function(item) {
      var isRemoved = false;
      if ($scope.selectedItems.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
          if ($scope.selectedItems[i].name.indexOf(item.name) > -1) {
            $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item), 1);
            isRemoved = true;
            break;
          }
          console.log("Checking..." + $scope.selectedItems[i].name.indexOf(item.name));
        }
      }
      //     else {
      if (!isRemoved) {
        $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
      }
      //   }
      console.log($scope.selectedItems)
    }
    $scope.addCustomItem = function() {}
  }
  var groceryCollection_JSON = [{
    "name": "Tomato",
    "type": "Roma"
  }, {
    "name": "Cauliflower",
    "type": "Organic"
  }, {
    "name": "Apple",
    "type": "Gala"
  }, {
    "name": "Orange",
    "type": "Sweet n' Sour"
  }, {
    "name": "Grapes",
    "type": "Wild"
  }];
  var selectedItems_JSON = [{
    "name": "Tomato",
    "type": "Roma"
  }];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="groceryApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="First Angular App">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Javascript, AngularJs">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <title>A simple AngularJs Application</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="groceryController">
  <h1>Welcome to my Grocery Store</h1>
  <p>Select your items from the options below.</p>
  <div ng-repeat="item in groceryCollection">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.name}}" value="{{item.name}}" ng-checked="selectedItems[$index].name.indexOf(item.name)>-1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)">
    <label for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
    <input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="5" placeholder="Quantity" />
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="others">
    <label for="others">Others</label>
  </p>
  <p>Please Enter your item if not displayed in the list above:</p>
  <p id="extraItems"> <span><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter your Item" ng-model="customItem"/></span>  <span><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter your Item Type" ng-model="customItemType"/></span>  <span><input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="5" placeholder="Quantity"/></span> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Add Item" ng-click="addItem();" />
  </p>
  <p> <a href="#">Add more items</a> 
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>Your selected items:</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="selection in selectedItems">
        <td>{{selection.name}}</td>
        <td>{{selection.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use selected flag on the items inside groceryCollection.

This gets rid of `toggleSelection` i.e. reduces to `ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected"`

and ng-checked is just `item.selected`.

The selected items simply filtered as `ng-repeat="selection in groceryCollection | filter: {selected:true}"`

All you are doing is in this process of selection we are only marking items that are selected.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("groceryApp", []).controller("groceryController", groceryControllerFunction);
  groceryControllerFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$filter"];

  function groceryControllerFunction($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.groceryCollection = groceryCollection;
    
    $scope.addCustomItem = function() {}
  }
  var groceryCollection = [{
    "name": "Tomato",
    "type": "Roma"
  }, {
    "name": "Cauliflower",
    "type": "Organic"
  }, {
    "name": "Apple",
    "type": "Gala"
  }, {
    "name": "Orange",
    "type": "Sweet n' Sour"
  }, {
    "name": "Grapes",
    "type": "Wild"
  }];
  
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="groceryApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="First Angular App">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Javascript, AngularJs">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <title>A simple AngularJs Application</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="groceryController">
  <h1>Welcome to my Grocery Store</h1>
  <p>Select your items from the options below.</p>
  <div ng-repeat="item in groceryCollection">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.name}}" value="{{item.name}}" ng-checked="item.selected" ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected">
    <label for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
    <input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="5" placeholder="Quantity" />
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="others">
    <label for="others">Others</label>
  </p>
  <p>Please Enter your item if not displayed in the list above:</p>
  <p id="extraItems"> <span><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter your Item" ng-model="customItem"/></span>  <span><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter your Item Type" ng-model="customItemType"/></span>  <span><input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="5" placeholder="Quantity"/></span> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Add Item" ng-click="addItem();" />
  </p>
  <p> <a href="#">Add more items</a> 
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>Your selected items:</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="selection in groceryCollection | filter: {selected:true}">
        <td>{{selection.name}}</td>
        <td>{{selection.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```